# Generating an HTML table with PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I've run into a problem with php, I have this table:

```
    <?php 
     $s=(" SELECT * FROM my_tbl");
     $W=mysql_query($s); 
     ?> 
     <table>
     <tr>
     <td> <center><strong>Member </strong></center></td> 
</tr><tr>
     <td> <center><strong> Total Meal </strong></center></td> 
     </tr> 
     <?php while ( $r=mysql_fetch_array($W)) {$i++; ?>
     <tr > <td> <?= $r["name"]; ?> </td></tr>
<tr>
     <td> <?= $r["tmeal"]; ?> </td>
     </tr><?php } ?>
     </table>
```

But I'm looking for this output:

[image: See the table below]

How can I improve my code so I can get this result?

Comment: Are these data coming from the database? Please show what you've tried.

Comment: Yes these data coming from the database.. Object Manipulator

Comment: what is your present code

Comment: Yes, agree with @RemyaR what have you tried so far?

Comment: Where is your html & php code?

Comment: i try this code $s=(" SELECT * FROM `my_tbl`");$W=mysql_query($s);
?>
<table><tr><td> <center><strong>Member </strong></center></td>
     <td> <center><strong> Total Meal </strong></center></td>
  </tr>
<?php while ( $r=mysql_fetch_array($W)) 
   {$i++;
   ?><tr >
       <td> <?= $r["name"]; ?> </td>
       <td> <?=  $r["tmeal"]; ?> </td>
       
                          </td></tr><?php }
?></table>

Answer (score 1):

```
 $conn = mysqli_connect('server','username','password',"DB NAme") or die("error");

 $queryString = "select * from TableNAme";
 $queryres    = mysqli_query($conn, $queryString) or die("not fire");

 echo "<table>";
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryres))
 {
   echo "<tr><td>$row[0]</td><td>$row[0]</td><td>$row[0]</td></tr>";
 }
 echo "</table>";
```

Comment: The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future, use mysqli or PDO instead mysql

Comment: Yes Sir i m agree with you Mr. Devs

Answer (score 1):

This may help you

```
 <?php
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "mypass") or  
      die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());  
  mysql_select_db("your_db"); 
  $s=(" SELECT * FROM my_tbl");
  $W=mysql_query($s); ?>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td> <center><strong>Member </strong></center></td> 
  <td> <center><strong> Total Meal </strong></center></td> 
  </tr> 
  <?php while ( $r = mysql_fetch_assoc($W)) { ?>
  <tr > <td> <? php echo $r['name']; ?></td> 
  <td> <? php echo $r['tmeal']; ?>  </td> 
   </tr><?php   } ?>
  </table>
```